# Could not find an option named "devtools-server-address". when trying to run flutter app from AndroidStudio

Tags: flutter, android-studio

I just updated Flutter plugin to 53.0.1, restarted Android Studio and hit "run" button and the error below show up:

```
Could not find an option named "devtools-server-address".
```

Answer (score 15):

Close and reopen AndroidStudio resolved for me!

`killall java`

Comment: If you downgraded while Android Studio was open you might see this error, as this answers suggest, just restart it and it will do.

Answer (score 6):

I downgraded from `Flutter 2.0` to `Flutter 1.22.5` and got this error.

To solve it,

Go to your terminal and write `flutter channel stable`.

Then run `flutter doctor`.

Now you may get another error like this -

[image]

If you have Flutter & Dart plugins already install, just ignore this error. This is a bug in `Flutter 1.22.5` .

Just run the app and it will work fine!

Comment: Flutter Doctor and IDE restart resolved this for me

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue but using VS Code on `stable` channel

- Execute the following commands:

```sh
flutter channel stable
flutter upgrade
flutter clean
flutter pub get
```

- Then, close and open your IDE

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps:

File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart. Run flutter clean Worked For me.

Answer (score 0):

This so simple... Open terminal type `flutter channel dev` this solve your problem.
And after that `flutter upgrade`
Finally, `flutter doctor`

> If it does not help:

Open terminal type `flutter channel stable`
And after that `flutter upgrade`
Finally, `flutter doctor`

Comment: I had same problem, but I was using `stable` channel, now I should switch to Dev?

Answer (score 0):

Working without upgrading flutter

Safe fix for Mac (Android Studio 4.1+). It is in a different directory now, but the symbolic link helps.

Just run this command in the Terminal:
ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.1/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.1

Change the version of the Android studio depending on what you have, I had 4.2 so used.

ln -s ~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/AndroidStudio4.2/plugins ~/Library/Application\ Support/AndroidStudio4.2

Answer (score 0):

Just Invalidate Cache and Restart. Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

**Just close your all project and also close Android Studio and Reopen.**