# I receive this error while trying to run Flutter app : Could not find an option named "devtools-server-address"

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, upgrade

I was developing a Flutter app using the `stable` channel, in Android Studio, now I upgraded Flutter Plugin to 53 and now when I try to run my app I receive this error

```
Could not find an option named "devtools-server-address".

Run 'flutter -h' (or 'flutter <command> -h') for available flutter commands and options.
```

Someone suggested using the `dev` channel, but I need to continue in the `stable` channel!

Suggestion Link:
[Could not find an option named "devtools-server-address". when trying to run flutter app from AndroidStudio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66215169/could-not-find-an-option-named-devtools-server-address-when-trying-to-run-flu)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just found the fix:

```
$ flutter upgrade
$ flutter clean
```

Then select **Invalidate Caches / Restart** from the Android Studio File menu!

Answer (score 2):

Follow the following steps:

1. Run the command **flutter clean** from terminal.
2. Go to **File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart -> Invalidate and Restart**.
3. Now try running your app. The issue should disappear.
4. If the error still persists: Go to File -> Settings -> Language & frameworks -> Flutter.
   Check that the sdk path is appropriate as shown in below image:
   [image: Flutter SDK path]

5. Check the Dart sdk path too:
   [image: Dart SDK Path]

6. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Follow the steps:

File -> Invalidate Cache and Restart.
Run flutter clean
Worked For me.

Comment: Ivalidate or Invalidate?

Answer (score 0):

For a little bit more details, you could also run `flutter doctor` to see what is happening.
In my case, I've recently updated Android Studio to version `4.2` and when I run the command it gives me:

```zsh
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel unknown, 1.22.6, on macOS 11.2.2 20D80 darwin-x64, locale en-GI)

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.4)
[!] Android Studio (version 4.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2019.3.3)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[!] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.1.2)
    ✗ Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
    ✗ Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 3 categories.
```

As well you could run `flutter doctor -v` as specified to get more details as *verbose* (where `-v` stands for *verbose*)

In my case the plugins where not visible for Android Studio and wasn't using a stable version of Flutter which didn't allow me to enable the plugins, although they were installed.

After this I've switched to a stable version of Flutter, double checked any required updated from Android Studio, uninstall and re-install the plugins and worked like a charm.

Want to mention that `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` were necesarry afterwards.